# Pandoc(md, latex) should generate bibitem in Bibliography

Tags: markdown, pandoc, pdflatex, bibtex, citations

With pandoc I am trying to produce a `.tex` file by combining a `.md` and a `.bib` file. In the resulting latex file, Pandoc already **formatted as plain text** the inline reference as well as the full reference in the bibliography. However, I like to have the references in `\cite` and `\bibitem` format, respectively.

example.md

```
---
title: Plain Text Workflow
author: Dennis Tenen, Grant Wythoff
date: January 20, 2014
bibliography: example.bib
---

# Section 1

Some sentence that needs citation [@fyfe_digital_2011 argues that too].

# Bibliography
```

example.bib

```
@article{fyfe_digital_2011,
    title = {Digital Pedagogy Unplugged},
    volume = {5},
    url = {http://digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/5/3/000106/000106.html},
    number = {3},
    urldate = {2013-09-28},
    author = {Fyfe, Paul},
    year = {2011},
    file = {fyfe_digital_pedagogy_unplugged_2011.pdf}
}
```

Pandoc command

```
pandoc example.md -t latex -s -S --filter pandoc-citeproc -o example.tex
```

example.tex (excerpt)

```
Some sentence that needs citation (Fyfe 2011 argues that too).

\section*{Bibliography}\label{bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}

Fyfe, Paul. 2011. ``Digital Pedagogy Unplugged'' 5 (3).
\url{http://digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/5/3/000106/000106.html}.
```

However, what I want to have is this (essentially what would be in the `.bbl` file generated by bibtex):

```
Some sentence that needs citation \citep[ argues that  too]{fyfe_digital_2011}.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Fyfe(2011)]{fyfe_digital_2011}
Paul Fyfe.
\newblock Digital pedagogy unplugged.
\newblock 5\penalty0 (3), 2011.
\newblock URL
  \url{http://digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/5/3/000106/000106.html}.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I know that I could run pandoc with `--natbib --bibliography=example.bib`, then compile with pdflatex and bibtex, and make use of `\input{example.bbl}`. But is there a way to do it properly with pandoc without having bibtex (manually or piped) in between?

By the way, how is pandoc doing it internally when it generates a pdf directly with `--filter pandoc-citeproc`? If it also just uses these preformatted plain text references, I would be deeply disappointed. Because it looks like that individual styles defined in the preamble of a latex template do not apply in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You cannot. Either you

- have pandoc generate the reference and bibliography for you (`pandoc-citeproc`, see point 2) 
  or
- have it format them for natbib (`--natbib`) or biblatex (`--biblatex`), but you have to rely on an external bibtex file (or [another compatible format](http://pandoc.org/README.html#citations)). You will then need `bibtex` or `biber` to format your citations.

2) `pandoc-citeproc` relies on csl styles. You can find some [here](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles) and [here](https://www.zotero.org/styles) and you can easily customize them [here](http://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/). Pass it to your pandoc command with `--csl=` or with a `csl:` line in the YAML title block. Pandoc looks for files in `~/.csl`, you have to give the full path if it's not there or in the same directory as your markdown file.